# How to configure a dockerfile to install CUDA 10.1?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, nvidia

I have a docker application and I need to configure its dockerfile to install cuda with 10.1 release

I tried

```
RUN apt install \
    nvidia-cuda-toolkit \
    -y
```

but after type nvcc --version, I have checked that cuda 9.1 was installed instead. How could I solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Is the OS from your base container even supported by CUDA 10.1? Generally it is easier to build on-top of one of the [official CUDA containers](https://hub.docker.com/r/nvidia/cuda/#!). You can also look if the [repo containing the recipe templates](https://gitlab.com/nvidia/container-images/cuda/-/tree/master) of those containers helps or the [Nvidia Container Toolkit](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker). I personally have previously used Nvidia's [HPC Container Maker (hpccm)](https://github.com/NVIDIA/hpc-container-maker) to create recipes.